# Got multiple Arguements in one function call but not in another function call

Tags: python-3.x, parameter-passing, robotframework, keyword-argument, positional-parameter

I am working on Robot Framework, one of my base method is written in python for building a SQL query with n columns and multiple where conditions. The function looks like,

```
from pypika import Query, Table, Field
def get_query_with_filter_conditions(table_name, *column, **where):
    table_name_with_no_lock = table_name + ' with (nolock)'
    table = Table(table_name_with_no_lock)
    where_condition = get_where_condition(**where)
    sql_query = Query.from_(table).select(
        *column
    ).where(
        Field(where_condition)
    )
    return str(sql_query).replace('"', '')
```

I am calling this method in my Robot keywords as:

```
Get Query With Filter Conditions    ${tableName}    ${column}    &{tableFilter}
```

This function is called in two other keywords. For one it works fine. for another it keeps throwing error as

> > > Keyword 'queryBuilderUtility.Get Query With Filter Conditions' got multiple values for argument 'table_name'.

The Keyword that works fine looks as:

```
Verify the ${element} in ${grid} is fetched from ${column} column in ${tableName} table from DB
    [Documentation]    Verifies Monetary values in the View Sale Grid
    ${feature}=    Get Variable Value    ${FEATURE_NAME}
    ${filterValue}=    Get Variable value    ${FILTER_VALUE}
    ${queryFilter}=    Get the Test Data    valid    ${filterValue}    ${feature}
    &{tableFilter}=    Create Dictionary
    Set To Dictionary    ${tableFilter}    ${filterValue}=${queryFilter}
    Set To Dictionary    ${tableFilter}    form_of_payment_type=${element}
    ${tableName}=    Catenate    SEPARATOR=.    SmartPRASales    ${tableName}
    ${query}=    Get query with Filter Conditions    ${tableName}    ${column}    &{tableFilter}
    Log    ${query}
    @{queryResult}=    CommonPage.Get a Column values from DB    ${query}
```

The functions That always throws error looks like:

```
Verify ${element} drop down contains all values from ${column} column in ${tableName} table
    [Documentation]    To verify the drop down has all values from DB
    ${feature}=    Get Variable Value    ${FEATURE_NAME}
    ${filterElement}=    Run Keyword If    '${element}'=='batch_type'    Set Variable    transaction_type
    ...    ELSE IF    '${element}'=='channel'    Set Variable    agency_type
    ...    ELSE    Set Variable    ${element}
    &{tableFilter}=    Create Dictionary
    Set To Dictionary    ${tableFilter}    table_name=GENERAL
    Set To Dictionary    ${tableFilter}    column_name=${filterElement}
    Set To Dictionary    ${tableFilter}    client_id=QR
    Log    ${tableFilter}
    Log    ${tableName}
    Log    ${column}
    ${tableName}=    Catenate    SEPARATOR=.    SmartPRAMaster    ${tableName}
    ${query}=    Get Query With Filter Conditions    ${tableName}    ${column}    &{tableFilter}
    Log    ${query}
    @{expectedvalues}=    CommonPage.Get a Column values from DB    ${query}
```

Can someone help me to get rectified what is the mistake I am doing here?

Comment: `${tableName}    ${column}    &{tableFilter}` check the content of all this 3 variables in both functions and if possible add same to the post

Comment: .@Dev 
For the working keyword:
 ${tableFilter} => {'document_no': '5088397227', 'form_of_payment_type': 'GF'}, ${tableName} => SmartPRASales.ticket_payment_details, ${column} => form_of_payment_amount. For the function that throws error: ${tableFilter} => {'table_name': 'GENERAL', 'column_name': 'sales_source', 'client_id': 'QR'} , ${tableName} => SmartPRAMaster.mas_list_of_values, ${column} => field_short_desc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to key value pair in the dictionary. One of the key in the dictionary

```
&{tableFilter}=    Create Dictionary
    Set To Dictionary    ${tableFilter}    table_name=GENERAL
```

is same as that of one of the argument in the

```
def get_query_with_filter_conditions(table_name, *column, **where):
```

Changed the argument in get_query_with_filter_conditions function from table_name to p_table_name and it worked. As the function takes positional arguments which can be specified as named parameter, python got confused with the table_name parameter I have passed with that of the key table_name in the dictionary.

Comment: You can accept your answer by clicking on hollow tick beside the answer after 24 hours of answer time